# How to pause and start adding rows to data grid view on button press in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have one application which can communicate with a connected hardware. When I turn on the hardware, the hardware will continuously send some data to the application. I am able to read the data from hardware in my application and record that data in to a dataGridView by adding rows for each data at run time.

Now i want to add a **'Pause'** button. When i press this button, my application should **stop adding new raw to the datagridview.**

**But the recording process should be continued in background.**

When i press the same button again, **all the recorded rows should be displayed and the process should continue.**

Please help I am new to C#.

Here is my code: I am using backgroundWorker.

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
     string StrMSGdata="";
     string tStamp="";
     // Here will get my data and process it.
     //Then
     backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, StrMSGdata + "#" + tStamp);


}

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{                               
       string recived   = e.UserState.ToString();
       string[] fullMsgData = new string[15];
       fullMsgData      = recived.Split('#');
       string msgData   = fullMsgData[0];
       string timStamp  = fullMsgData[1];
       dataGridView1.Rows.Add(timStamp,msgData);
    }
```

Comment: Your question is really broad, as you don't give any existing code as starting point. you'd rather try to work on a solution and come with questions when you encounter problems on the way.

Comment: When you pause simply add the data to a queue, and when you resume read the data from the queue and add it to the grid. If you have an issue with either task then ask a question specific to the issue.

Comment: Please try to add more some snippets so we can understand what you are actually doing, and help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's emulate the hardware:

```
public class Hardware
{
    System.Timers.Timer _timer;
    public event EventHandler Send;

    public Hardware()
    {
        _timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        _timer.Interval = 1000;
        _timer.Elapsed += _timer_Elapsed;
        _timer.Start();
    }

    void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Send(this, new SendArgs(DateTime.Now.Ticks));
    }

    public class SendArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public long Id { get; private set; }
        public SendArgs(long id)
        {
            Id = id;
        }
    }
}
```

In your main form, you may add a collection object which will temporarily hold the values:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<object> _queue = new List<object>();
    bool _paused = false;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Id", "Id");
        var h = new Hardware();
        h.Send += h_Send;
    }

    void h_Send(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var value = ((Hardware.SendArgs)e).Id;
        if (_paused)
        {
            _queue.Add(value);
        }
        else
        {
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(value);
                }));
            }
        }
    }

    private void pauseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _paused = !_paused;
        pauseButton.Text = (_paused) ? "Start" : "Pause";
        if (!_paused)
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
                {
                    _queue.ForEach(item =>
                    {
                        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(item);
                    });
                    _queue.Clear();
                }));
            }
            else
            {
                _queue.ForEach(item =>
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(item);
                });
                _queue.Clear();
            }
    }
}
```

[EDIT] Here's a version for the code sample in your updated question:

```
List<object> _queue = new List<object>();
bool _paused = false;

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    string StrMSGdata = "";
    string tStamp = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        StrMSGdata = i.ToString();
        tStamp = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i, StrMSGdata + "#" + tStamp);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(
    object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string recived = e.UserState.ToString();
    string[] fullMsgData = new string[15];
    fullMsgData = recived.Split('#');
    string msgData = fullMsgData[0];
    string timStamp = fullMsgData[1];
    if (_paused)
    {
        _queue.Add(new[]{ timStamp, msgData });
    }
    else
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(timStamp, msgData);
    }
}

private void pauseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _paused = !_paused;
    pauseButton.Text = (_paused) ? "Start" : "Pause";
    if (!_paused)
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
            {
                _queue.ForEach(item =>
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(item);
                });
                _queue.Clear();
            }));
        }
        else
        {
            _queue.ForEach(item =>
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add((string[])item);
            });
            _queue.Clear();
        }
}
```